# Is there any way to revert preventDefault method in Vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

I'm trying to create a horizontal scrolling container. In a precise case i need to revert e.preventDefault(); from a click.

I tried a lot of options, changing 'window.location.href' in the else statement seems to be a great option.
But i can't figure how to grab the href from the link clicked.

Any idea can help to achieve my goal. :)

```
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    isDown = false;

    // Disable click event (for ever unfortunately)
    if(moved === true) {
        this.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    } else {
        // trying to reset click function
    }
```

Comment: so on every mouse up you are binding a new event listener.... that is a bad design. You are going to have a lot of event listeners added.

Comment: My tip: don't add an eventlistener in an eventlistener. Add them outside, and then make logic to handle all your cases inside them.

Comment: Perhaps try toggling a class that removes all pointer events instead of using the event object to prevent default behavior. Here's MDN on `pointer-events: none` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: @some using the same function reference will not add multiple handlers with the same reference.

Comment: @AndreiTodorut Not sure what you are talking about, using same function with addEventListener does not magically make it called once.

Comment: it is called once, if you add the same reference

Comment: @epascarello [Yes it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Multiple_identical_event_listeners)

Comment: @AndreiTodorut But is is NOT the same. Is just have the same definition but every time the mouse up event is fired (and moved === true) a new, never used arrow function is created and then added to listen for the click event. Do 5 mouse up on the element and you have added 5 click handlers. Try it yourself. Add a `console.log("clicked")` or something in that inner function and you will see that is fired multiple times if more than one mouse-up event has been fired.

Comment: @some I think you might have misunderstood the comment that was in reply to yours. My interpretation was that it was a _suggestion_ to create a function reference that can be added within an event handler, not an _observation_ that this was already happening in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally prevent a click event from firing on your slider by registering a `click` event listener that shares the `moved` variable with your `mousedown` and `mousemove` event listeners.

The [`{ passive: true }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters) option indicates that the listener does not call `event.preventDefault()`, and saves a lot CPU time particularly for the `mousemove` event which can fire several times per second.

The `true` parameter indicates that the event listener should be called *before* the event starts to bubble up from the target element. This allows it to prevent propagation even to listeners that were already added on the same element, as long as they didn't also set `useCapture` to `true`.

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');

// prevent this if mousemove occurred between mousedown and mouseup
slider.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('click event fired on slider');
});

// fires just before click event
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  console.log('mouseup event fired on slider');
});

let moved = false;

// reset for each potential click
slider.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
  moved = false;
});

// indicate cancellation should occur for click
slider.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
  moved = true;
}, { passive: true });

// prevents click event if mousemove occurred between mousedown and mouseup
slider.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (moved) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
}, true);
```

```html
<input type="range" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much Patrick! I had to remove the { passive: true } option from the mousemove event listener since i need an event. 
Otherwise your script is working just perfectly!

Comment: @Biscuite `since i need an event` you can still provide `{ passive: true }` as long as you don't call `event.preventDefault()` within the callback.

Comment: I use event.preventDefault(); to prevent default behavior from browsers such as image grabbing. So, unfortunately CPU performance will fall a bit.

Comment: @Biscuite that doesn't explain why you need to `preventDefault()` on a `mousemove` event, but okay...

Comment: I tried to remove event.preventDefault(); from mousemove but everytime i try to click and drag my slider the browser grabs an image instead of the container.

Comment: @Biscuite Prevent the default on [`dragstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/dragstart_event), not `mousemove`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Seems like i have a lot more to learn! Thanks for your time Patrick

Answer (score -1):

You should remove the event listener containing the `event.preventDefault();`.

In order to do that you have to save your function reference into a variable like so:

```
const preventClickHandler = (e) => e.preventDefault;
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    isDown = false;

    // Disable click event (for ever unfortunately)
    if(moved === true) {
        this.addEventListener('click', preventClickHandler);
    } else {
        this.removeEventListener('click', preventClickHandler);
    }
})
```

Comment: `(e) => e.preventDefault` might as well be `() => {}`. It's a no-op.